# How do I add dielectric Breakdown Voltage of air in Multisim?

Tags: voltage, multisim, dielectric-breakdown

For my simulation, I need to add a component that represents air with dielectric breakdown voltage of 1 kV. How do I do that?

Comment: just a fancy guess, a 100Meg resistor in series with a 10^-5 A fuse, in parallel to the voltage difference of interest. If simulation includes a fuse.

Comment: but a fuse would open, not close, in the case of breakdown!

Comment: it would  have made more sense to use a DIAC with a 1 us RC using 10M:10k divider to 100 pf

Answer (score 0):

Search for “spark gap model SPICE” and you’ll find examples. Breakdown has a negative resistance characteristic.

GDTs also have similar characteristics.